# localizedStandardCompare: sort error when sorting times that lack a trailing zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sorting

I'm sorting arrays of times like this:

```
00:26.39    
00:23.49
00:26.9
```

When I attempt to sort ascending using `localizedStandardCompare:`, however, the results turn out like this:

```
00:23.49
00:26.9
00:26.39
```

I suspect the error has something to do with the absence of a trailing zero on the `00:26.9` time, but I need for these to sort properly even if the data has been input as shown.

Is there a different search selector I could be using that would handle this correctly? Or some other simple solution apart from rolling my own sorter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should to change each and every value into float than string to avoid this type of condition try this one:

```
NSArray *arrOne = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[@"26.39" floatValue]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[@"26.49" floatValue]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[@"26.9" floatValue]],nil];

    NSLog(@"00:26.39 < 00:26.49  %d",[[arrOne objectAtIndex:0] localizedStandardCompare:[arrOne objectAtIndex:1]]);

    NSLog(@"00:26.49 > 00:26.39 %d",[[arrOne objectAtIndex:1]  localizedStandardCompare:[arrOne objectAtIndex:0]]);

    NSLog(@"00:26.49 < 00:26.9 %d",[[arrOne objectAtIndex:1]  localizedStandardCompare:[arrOne objectAtIndex:2]]);

    NSLog(@"00:26.49 == 00:26.49 %d",[[arrOne objectAtIndex:1]  localizedStandardCompare:[arrOne objectAtIndex:1]]);
```

Comment: While I recognize this might work for my purposes, it seems extremely inefficient when sorting large arrays of values.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since for my specific case performance isn't an issue. My final, sorted arrays are small enough that a slow-down here shouldn't be noticeable. A note for anyone reading this in the future though that heavy string operations like this aren't efficient for large arrays...

Comment: So it is, i am continue thinking on this point,and as i get any sufficient thing i will update this one.